# Error in Implementing levelplot in R for a Categorical Raster with RAT

Tags: r, levelplot

I have a raster in .tif format which I am trying to visualize in R using levelplot. Here is what I have done so far:

```
library(raster)
library(lattice)

data_tif <- raster("fthrt14_21.tif", RAT = TRUE)
data_tif

rat <- read.dbf("fthrt14_21.tif.vat.dbf")
rat
data_tif <- ratify(data_tif)
colnames(rat)[1] <- "ID"
levels(data_tif) <- rat


levelplot(data_tif, col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(5)),main = "Fire Threats"
          , attr(THRT_CLASS))
```

I am getting an error: Error in UseMethod("levelplot") : 
  no applicable method for 'levelplot' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"

How can I resolve this error? This is what my RAT looks like:

[image]

```r
# Code for getting reproducible example of RAT file
Value <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Count <- c(15918472,127852558,102695341,108155367,8927377)
THRT_CLASS <- c("Low","Moderate","High","Very High","Extreme")

RAT <- data.frame(Value,Count,THRT_CLASS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a bit tricky! First thing is loading `raster` and `lattice` libraries and then using `lattice::levelplot` for plotting categorical raster. However, you should be using `rasterVis::levelplot` for this purpose.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)


## Example data
r <- raster(ncol=4, nrow=2)
r[] <- sample(1:4, size=ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
r <- as.factor(r)

## Add a landcover column to the Raster Attribute Table
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat[["landcover"]] <- c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers","water bodies")
levels(r) <- rat

## Plot
rasterVis::levelplot(r, col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(4)), xlab="", ylab="")
```

then you get this plot:
[image]
However, if you use below script you bump into error message:

```
> levelplot(r, col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(4)), xlab="", ylab="")
```

> Error in UseMethod("levelplot") :    no applicable method for
>   'levelplot' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster',
>   'BasicRaster')"

Note that even if you only load `raster` package (not `lattice`), you may still see this error as the `lattice` and `rasterVis` share same function `levelplot` and `raster` package automatically loads `lattice`. To get around this use `rasterVis::levelplot`.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I didn't know there are different types of levelplot function in different libraries.